# Creating Custom Binding programmatically

Tags: .net, wcf, binding, web-config, app-config

We need compression in our WCF Web Service and have already found a good solution:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53718/Extending-WCF-Part-II

There's only one problem. Configuration files are no option. How those Custom Bindings can be created in code?

```
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="ZipBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
    sendTimeout="00:10:00">
      <customMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="mtomMessageEncoding" 
    messageEncoderType="YourAssemblyName.YourMessageEncoder, 
    WcfExtensions">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="999999999" 
            maxStringContentLength="999999999" 
    maxArrayLength="999999999" maxBytesPerRead="999999999" 
    maxNameTableCharCount="999999999">
        </readerQuotas>
      </customMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport maxBufferSize="999999999" 
        maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999" 
    authenticationScheme="Anonymous" 
    proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" useDefaultWebProxy="true"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

This is what i've come up with:

```
MessageEncodingBindingElementExtension customMessageEncoding = new MessageEncodingBindingElementExtension
{
    InnerMessageEncoding = "binaryMessageEncoding",
    MessageEncoderType = "WcfExtensions.GZipMessageEncoder, WcfExtensions",
};
customMessageEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 999999999;
customMessageEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 999999999;
customMessageEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 999999999;
customMessageEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 999999999;
customMessageEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 999999999;

CustomBinding zipBinding = new CustomBinding(customMessageEncoding, new HttpTransportBindingElement
{
    MaxBufferSize = 999999999,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 999999999,
    AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous,
    ProxyAuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous,
    UseDefaultWebProxy = true
});

zipBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
zipBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
zipBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
zipBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
```

But for some reason CustomBinding doesn't accept customMessageEncoding...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter in the constructor for the type `CustomBinding` accepts only a `BindingElement` subclass. The class you have specified is a `BindingElementExtensionElement` subclass (used for customising the configuration Xml).

Instead of passing a subclass of the `BindingElementExtensionElement` into the `CustomBinding` constructor, you should create an suitable subclass instance of a `BindingElement`(e.g. `BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement`) and call the `BindingElementExtensionElement`’s `ApplyConfiguration` method, passing in the `BindingElement`.

Then pass the instance of the `BindingElement` into the `CustomBinding` constructor.

```
BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement encodingElement = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();
customMessageEncoding.ApplyConfiguration(encodingElement);

CustomBinding zipBinding = new CustomBinding(encodingElement, new HttpTransportBindingElement
{
    MaxBufferSize = 999999999,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 999999999,
    AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous,
    ProxyAuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous,
    UseDefaultWebProxy = true
});
```