# Add ServiceHost extension by code

Tags: wcf, web-services, webhttpbinding

I have this XML snipped of a `App.config` which I [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="gzipMessageEncoding" type="Microsoft.Samples.GZipEncoder.GZipMessageEncodingElement, GZipEncoder, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
...
```

For some reasons I don't want to hardcode the asembly and I don't want to use a XML file for that.

Curriently I use this code:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:80/Test");
WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding(
                                    WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ExampleWebService), baseAddress);
host.Extensions.Add(new GZipMessageEncodingElement());
```

But the last line does not work how can I fix that? I think it must be possible to do that by code.

---

Curriently I found almost an solution I have just a problem when I try to use the JsonSerialisator however I use this binding now:

```
CustomBinding cb = new CustomBinding(binding);
MessageEncodingBindingElement inner = (MessageEncodingBindingElement)cb.Elements.ToArray()[0];
cb.Elements.RemoveAt(0);
cb.Elements.Insert(0, new GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement(inner));
```

The `GZipMessageEncoder` is a little modified to make the compression optinal:

```
public override ArraySegment<byte> WriteMessage(Message message, int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset) {
    var req = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
    var encoding=req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding]; // crash while debug
    //Use the inner encoder to encode a Message into a buffered byte array
    ArraySegment<byte> buffer = innerEncoder.WriteMessage(message, maxMessageSize, bufferManager, 0);
    if(encoding != null && encoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip")) {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentEncoding] = "gzip";
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentEncoding] = "gzip";
        //Compress the resulting byte array
        return CompressBuffer(buffer, bufferManager, messageOffset);
    } else {
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

But my code let visual studio crash while debugging in the marked line. Any ideas?

Comment: looks like similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534478/creating-custom-binding-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work this way. `WebHttpBinding` will never use your binding element. `BindingElementExtensions` in configuration file just defines new elements which can be used to define `CutomBinding` in the config file. If you need to do that in the code you just create a new instance of `CustomBinding` and fill it with binding elements you want to use (classes derived from `BindingElement`) - you will use`GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement`. The linked sample describes that code as well:

```
ICollection<BindingElement> bindingElements = new List<BindingElement>();
HttpTransportBindingElement httpBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement compBindingElement = new GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement ();
bindingElements.Add(compBindingElement);
bindingElements.Add(httpBindingElement);
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(bindingElements);
```

Comment: Curriently I developed a very similar code but while debugging my whole visual studio crashes.